# Why do my font choices not appear when setting symbology in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.2, font

I have noticed this, it seems to be a bug.  I will set the typeface for the symbology for one legend/feature class, but as soon as I want to apply it to another feature class the font grays out or is not available to use.  However, if I restart ArcGIS, it works fine.  The problem was initially only occurring for a downloaded font, now it is happening with system fonts also.  I am using ArcGIS 10.2.